# How to get mDNS on Android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, dns, mdns

Asking this again because all the similar questions I see asked are very old at this point. I'm currently running Android 14 and have tested a .local address that works just fine on my PC but not on Android. I've tried with Chrome, Edge, and my own Unity3D app. I've also testd with another Android device on 13. Supposedly mDNS support was added to Android 12+ but I can say as of right now this does not work for me. Is there something I need to enable or is this just broken again?

Comment: I'm using .local addresses successfully on (stock Pixel) Android 12 without any configuration; maybe they broke it later, but could it be that it's your router/accesspoint that's blocking the use of multicast over Wi-Fi? (I know that's a thing especially in managed multi-AP networks, and sometimes on residential gateways as well.)

Comment: Do you have any iPhone to test with? At least iOS 12 also supports .local lookup via mDNS. // Since mDNS also covers DNS-SD service discovery (which Android actually got even earlier, before it got support for .local hostnames), could you try installing any "DNS-SD browser" / "Bonjour browser" app such as 'HE.NET Network Tools' and see if it's able to detect any advertised services? (Assuming the LAN has any, that is.)

Comment: My PC is connected over WiFi and has no issues with the address lookup, so I don't believe that's it. My phone is a pixel as well as my tablet. Perhaps you're right they broke it in later versions.